# Trying to create a submission form with preview

Tags: php, forms, preview

I am trying to make this form be able to submit a post and create a page with auto indexing and also be able to preview the page being created before hand. Can someone help? Thank you in advance, I am pretty bad with PHP files.

```css
#wrapper{
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 200px;
 padding-left: 50px;
 padding-right: 50px;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
 padding-top: 50px;
 background-color: #2C2C2C;
 position: relative;
 width: 70%;
 max-width: 1250px;
 min-width: 300px;
 z-index: 1;
 color: white;
 text-decoration-color: white;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 20px 5px #000;
}
.form-control .header {
 width: 90%;
 outline: inset #6B6B6B;
 margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div align="center" id="wrapper">
<h2>Welcome Back &#60;Insert Name&#62;!</h2>
<form id="submission" method="post" action="submission-handler.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 Blog Title:<center></center>
 <br>
 Blog Content:<center><textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your blog post here" rows="10" required></textarea>
   <textarea name="header" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Blog Post Header" rows="2" required></textarea>
 </center>
 <br>
 Upload an image: (Not Currently Working)
 <center><input type="file" name="filetoupload" id="filetoupload" disabled></center>
 <br>
 <br>
 <hr>
 <br>
 <br>
 <input type="submit" class="form-control submit" value="Preview Post" disabled>
 <input type="submit" class="form-control submit" value="Finalize Post" disabled>
</form>
</div>
```

The actual page looks different than shown up on here. If anybody needs a reference  , [here](https://timescapeinc.com/Submission_Form_2B4235x21651a15978y3B1058175Bkhw18501W1x_Post.html)

Comment: What did you mean preview here

Comment: _"create a page with auto indexing"_ - What does that mean?

Comment: @ZainFarooq preview as in it shows a rough preview of the blog posts being typed into the forms before hand, basically want it to open a new tab and preview what the post would look like on a page.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson auto indexing where you create a webpage and it will automatically create the extension to be "blogpost.html?*Insert extension* that or it will automatically create a randomized name for the HTML file that cannot be repeated.

Comment: That's not really called "auto indexing" (indexing pages is what search engine does). That's simply creating a dynamic URL. Most common is to use a router with a dynamic url segment and call the pages something like `/post/foo`, `/post/bar` and so on. However, the question about how to do that is too broad (and there are multiple ways). I would recommend that you look into using some router.

Answer (score 0):

based on your code above your trying to pass a value to another page..

try to put this code in submission-handler.php

```
   <?php
   $message = $_POST['message'];
   $header = $_POST['header'];
   echo $message;
   echo "<br>";
   echo $header; 
   ?>
```

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to make it so I can plug the values into a template already made for each blogger on my website. Though I need it to be able to auto index pages. For instance Blogpost.html?index1 Blogpost.html?index2 etc.

Comment: what do you mean by 'auto index pages'

Comment: I just showed an example so basically when you go to create a web page it will automatically index them so instead of being "blogpost.html" it would create them as "blogpost.html?index1", "blogpost.html?index2" and so on. I noticed that you were more focused on the preview aspect than the creation.